# Regex for find and replace in N++ of number followed by anything

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file with the following lines:

```
asm-java-2.0.0-lib
cib-slides-3.1.0
lib-hibernate-common-4.0.0-beta
astp
act4lib-4.0.0
```

I want to remove everything from, including the '-' before the numbers begin so the results look like:

```
2.0.0-lib
3.1.0
4.0.0-beta
act4lib
```

Does anyone know the correct regex for this? So far I have come up with `-\D.*(a-z)*` but its got too many errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*?(?=\d|$)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  .*?       # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  (?=       # start lookahead, zero-length assertion that makes sure we have after
    \d      # a digit
   |        # OR
    $       # end of line
  )         # end lookahead
```

**Result for given example:**

```
2.0.0-lib  
3.1.0  
4.0.0-beta
```

---

**Another solution that deals with `act4lib-4.0.0`:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:.*-(?=\d)|\D+)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  (?:       # start non capture group
    .*      # 0 or more any character but newline
    -       # a dash
    (?=\d)  # lookahead, zero-length assertion that makes sure we have a digit after
   |        # OR
    \D+     # 1 or more non digit
  )         # end group
```

**Replacement:**

```
\t          # a tabulation, you may replace with what you want
```

**Given:**

```
asm-java-2.0.0-lib  
cib-slides-3.1.0  
lib-hibernate-common-4.0.0-beta
astp
act4lib-4.0.0
```

**Result for given example:**

```
2.0.0-lib  
3.1.0  
4.0.0-beta
4.0.0
```

Comment: Seems harder work to search for the preceding string with a lookahead assertion that it's followed by a number then delete the preceding string bit.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
^\D+\-
```

If you want to completely remove lines without numbers then use this

```
^\D+(\-|$)
```

In case the packages contain numbers in their names like `act4lib-4.0.0` then a longer variant is needed

```
^[\w-]+(\-(?=\d+\.\d+)|$)
```

It can be shortened to `^.+?(\-(?=\d+\.)|$)` but I just want to be sure so I also check the minor version number

The `^` will match from the start of line

Comment: works fine, until there is a line without numbers such as "astp". So instead of completely eliminating that line, it completely ignores it.

Comment: @Ziyad you didn't post a reproducible sample and what I said works fine with your text in the post

Comment: Yeah. It did work for the first sample I posted. However at that time I forgot to consider the latter scenario. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for the task I had. However, if you have certain alphanumeric combinations or names such as "org_company", "org.company", I don' think this will work properly.

Comment: @Ziyad `\D` will match any non-digit characters, and `o`, `_` or `.` are also some of them

Comment: If you have alphanumeric character such as "act4lib-4.0.0" , I don't think it will work.