# PHP get matched order id using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm working on a PHP code which need to grab some order ids from texts, the order ids formats are like below

```
  Ex- 
          201812321910AT
          201812321810AT        
          201812321910AT-001
          201812321910AT-001
```

Those have inside texts like below

```
      lorem ispmes dolter yexy tesy 201812321910AT l tesyui lorem ispmes 
dolter gjexy tesy    201812321810AT hekfl lorem tesxts
 201812321910AT-001 lot kyesu oerd 201812321910AT-001 lfs tes ol sghn
```

I tried this code, but it also returns some other matched words which have 12-15 letters

```
preg_match('/\b[A-Z]{12,15}\b/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

I haven't advanced knowledge with php preg_match patterns, can someone help me to get matched order ids using PHP. 
the above order ids are examples only **normally order id have 12 numbers then AT letter**, and **some orders have 12 numbers the AT then 3 numbers followed by -** .

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "matched" -- what is your expected output?

Comment: Do you have some rationale for order ids? Can you add more samples for order ids? For the data you have given you can match it with `^\b\d{12}[A-Z]{2}(?:-\d{3}\b)?$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ODs0b4/1)

Comment: sorry i edited the question

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Thank you i'll check  your reg expression

Comment: @SunethKalhara: The regex I gave only matches as a whole. If you want to collect such kind of order ids from a text, just needed to remove `^` and `$` anchors from the regex. I've added it as answer. Hope that works for you.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-on-demand service, no matter how over-eager the people who already answered may be. You need to show us what you tried, and explain how it failed to meet your expectations, then we help you fix it.

Comment: @Sammitch I forgot to add that code, pls reopen the question

Comment: @Sammitch Also i want to say some of above voters who cast for close question, answered slimier questions before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129074/regex-for-find-and-replace-in-n-of-number-followed-by-anything/54130413#54130413
when the beginners start to answer the question they voting for close question.better to avoid those kind of hate and jealousy

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from posting a second, better question. Once it falls off the front page you're not likely to get any decent responses anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to make it more complex than it it.
Capture 12 digits then anything lazy until a space.

```
preg_match_all("/(\d{12}AT.*?)\s/", $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "201812321910AT "
    [1]=>
    string(15) "201812321810AT "
    [2]=>
    string(19) "201812321910AT-001 "
    [3]=>
    string(19) "201812321910AT-001 "
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "201812321910AT"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "201812321810AT"
    [2]=>
    string(18) "201812321910AT-001"
    [3]=>
    string(18) "201812321910AT-001"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/S4CSr

Comment: Thank You for the answer, worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

This regex should be good enough for capturing those order ids in your post,

```
\b\d{12}[A-Z]{2}(?:-\d{3}\b)?
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ODs0b4/2)**